# Como podría mostrar las imágenes almacenadas en el servidor de la base de datos en android studio con java?

Tags: java, android, imagen, studio, picasso

Llevo desde el inicio de mi proyecto intentando mostrar las imágenes de los socios almacenadas en una carpeta del servidor de mi base de datos, y no lo he logrado hasta ahora

Llevo videos, manuales, búsquedas y webs infinitas, en todas veo cosas parecidas, pero en la gran mayoría esas imágenes las toman de la misma web.

Yo lo que deseo es cogerlas desde una carpeta PHOTO compartida

Al servidor llego a través de una ip dinámica que vamos a suponer sea "mi_ip_dinamica.net"
Utilizo URL = "\mi_ip_dinamica.net\Equipo-BaseDatos\PHOTO"
Si voy a red veo mi equipo y mi carpeta compartida, en ubicación pone: \Equipo-BaseDatos, recurso \PHOTO

He intentando varias formas, esta con la librería picasso

```
String extImg = ".jpg";
```

private String imageURL = "\mi_ip_dinamica.net\Equipo-BaseDatos\PHOTO";

String nImagen = metodoObtenerNumeroImagen();

```
    String rutaImg = imageURL + nImagen + extImg;

    Picasso.with(this)

            .load(rutaImg)

            .error(R.drawable.avestruz)

            .fit()

            .centerInside()

            .into(Cimagen);
```

En el métodoObtenerNumeroImagen, lo que hago, es preguntar a la base de datos por el número de usuario, la imagen de cada usuario se almacena nombrada por ese número.jpg

Alguien podría darme alguna idea ?
Que estoy haciendo mal, que me falta por hacer, como podría reorientar mi proyecto
Alguna ayudita, porfisssss ?

Gracias por la respuesta Jorgesys.

Con ip dinámica, me refiero al servidor de changeip.com, o sea, mi ip pública, que es dinámica, está enlazada al servicio de changeip, por lo que funciona como si fuera una ip estática fija.

Cuando mencionas, en el string de imageURL, aquí es donde estoy algo perdido, no se si es:

```
"https://mi_ip_dinamica.net/Equipo-BaseDatos/PHOTO";
```

o:

```
"https://mi_ip_dinamica.net/PHOTO";
```

Pues la carpeta la tengo compartida y en la misma carpeta me dice que su dirección de red es:

```
//equipoLocal/photo.
```

Tampoco sabría si tengo que abrir puertos espacíficos en el router para picasso. actualmente abro el puerto 136 para http:// ó 445 para https://.

Pero de ninguna de las dos formas logro hacerlo funcionar

Otro problema que veo, es que cuando pongo la URI en el navegador, éste se queda en blanco sin cargar ninguna imagen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el código que muestras no debería existir ningún problema al cargar la imagen desde una url, rutaImg debe contener la url de la imagen:

```
 Picasso.with(this)
            .load(rutaImg)
            .error(R.drawable.avestruz)
            .fit()
            .centerInside()
            .into(Cimagen);
```

Si estas creando la ruta de la imagen de esta forma:

```
private String imageURL = "\mi_ip_dinamica.net\Equipo-BaseDatos\PHOTO";

String nImagen = metodoObtenerNumeroImagen();

 String rutaImg = imageURL + nImagen + extImg;
```

primero debes asegurar usar el protocolo https: en

private String imageURL = "https://mi_ip_dinamica.net/Equipo-BaseDatos/PHOTO";

después **debes asegurar que el valor de `rutaImg` sea una url que al cargarla en el navegador del dispositivo se pueda visualizar**.

```
 String rutaImg = imageURL + nImagen + extImg;
```

**Aquí el problema que veo es que al usar una ip dinámica puede ser que cuando uses la url la ip en donde se encuentra la imagen ya no exista, debería ser una ip fija.**

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Jorgesys.

He editado mi pregunta para responder lo que me comentas

Muchas gracias

Comment: Solo asegura que la url que construyes y se almacena en la variable rutaImg  es una url valida de imagen, es un poco problemático si usas una ip dinámica, puede servirte momentáneamente y después ya no..., saludos.