# Cargar imágenes en ImageView android studio con librería Picasso desde variable

Tags: java, android, android-studio, picasso

He seguido varios manuales y vistas varias respuestas sobre el tema, pero mis escasos conocimientos me permiten dar con la solución, por eso recurro a vosotros.

Deseo cargar la imagen de un socio en un `activity`. Las imágenes las tengo en la carpeta `drawables`.

Si cargo la imagen de forma individual utilizando `R.dragable.3904123`, la imagen carga sin problemas

Si utilizo variables para obtener esa misma dirección de la imagen, ésta no se muestra.

```
private void metodoCargarImagen() {
   //este método lo usaba para obtener la URL de la imagen del servidor, ahora obtengo(R.dragable.)
    String imagenURL = miConexion.metodoEnviarRutaImagenes();
    //este método lo utilizo para obtener el nombre de la imagen, en este caso(3904123)
    String nImagen = metodoObtenerNumeroImagen(socio);
    //aqui concateno (R.dragable. + a + 3904123)
    String rutaImg = imagenURL + "a" + nImagen;
    //convierto el String en URI ?
    Uri uriImagen = Uri.parse(rutaImg);
    //Agrega imagen al ImageView.
    Picasso.with(this)
            .load(uriImagen) //con este método, a la derecha me aparece el texto "RequestCreator"
            .error(R.drawable.avestruz)
            .fit()
            .centerInside()
            .into(img_vS_img);
}
```

Este es el código de la imagen:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_vS_img"
    android:layout_width="102dp"
    android:layout_height="145dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/avestruz" />
```

Este sería el código cargando la misma dirección de la imagen, pero de forma individual:

```
private void metodoCargarImagen() {
    String imagenURL = miConexion.metodoEnviarRutaImagenes();
    String nImagen = metodoObtenerNumeroImagen(socio);
    //Uri rutaImg = imagenURL + "a" + nImagen + extImg;
    String rutaImg = imagenURL + "a" + nImagen;
    //Uri uriImage = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/"+ rutaImg);
    //Crea ruta de la imagen.
    //rutaImg = rutaImg.replace("@drawable/", "android.resource://"+ getPackageName() +"/drawable/");
    //Obtiene la uri de la imagen.
    Uri uriImagen = Uri.parse(rutaImg);
    //Agrega imagen al ImageView.
    Picasso.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.a3904123)  //Me sigue apareciendo "RequestCreator" pero la imagen es visible
            .error(R.drawable.avestruz)
            .fit()
            .centerInside()
            .into(img_vS_img);
}
```

[image: imagen del código por variable]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La posibilidad de cargar la imagen sin convertirla en Uri, la habia descartado previamente por no funcionarme tampoco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R.drawable.a3904123` es un `int` que corresponde al id de la imagen. No es lo mismo que la string `"R.drawable.a3904123"`. Convertirla a uri tampoco la hace válida. De hecho ese paso no hace ninguna diferencia porque es lo que hace Picasso internamente cuando le pasas una string.

Para que la uri sea válida debe tener este formato

```
String imagenURL = "android.resource://"+ getPackageName() +"/drawable/";
String nImagen = metodoObtenerNumeroImagen(socio);
String rutaImg = imagenURL + "a" + nImagen;
```

Pero tambíen puedes cargar la imagen a partir de su id

```
String nImagen = metodoObtenerNumeroImagen(socio);
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("a"+nImagen, "drawable", getPackageName());
Picasso.with(this)
        .load(resId)
        .error(R.drawable.avestruz)
        .fit()
        .centerInside()
        .into(img_vS_img);
```

Comment: Por fin me funciona.
Copié tu código para cargar la imagen a partir de su id. Ahora me funciona perfecto. Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Tengo otra pregunta sobre el mismo tema, pero en lugar de obtener la imagen desde la propia aplicación, la quería abrir desde el disco duro del pc donde tengo la base de datos, que hace de servidor SQL.

La pregunta es ésta:
[enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/449436/como-podr%c3%ada-mostrar-las-im%c3%a1genes-almacenadas-en-el-servidor-de-la-base-de-datos)_cursiva_**negrita**

Comment: Esa pregunta no está relacionada a android. Tu código es correcto pero si no puedes ver la imagen en un navegador, tampoco se verá en tu app. Deberías formular de nuevo la pregunta pero enfocada en la configuración del servidor. La app es irrelevante en ese caso

Comment: Gracias Sinner of the System. Entonces mañana mismo replantearé una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, Sinner of the System, sería abusar de tu buena fe, el que pudieras mirarme si hay solución a ésta pregunta que tengosobre cargar las imágenes en una vista personalizada ?

[Enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/452549/mostrar-im%c3%a1genes-en-vista-personalizada-de-listview-y-simplecursoradapter-con-an)

Answer (score 1):

Si estas usando `Picasso` no tienes que convertir la url a `URI`, puedes cargar la direcciòn url para que cargue la imagen, solo asegura que la variable `rutaImg` contenga una url valida de imagen.

```
private void metodoCargarImagen() {
   //este método lo usaba para obtener la URL de la imagen del servidor, ahora obtengo(R.dragable.)
    String imagenURL = miConexion.metodoEnviarRutaImagenes();
    //este método lo utilizo para obtener el nombre de la imagen, en este caso(3904123)
    String nImagen = metodoObtenerNumeroImagen(socio);
    //aqui concateno (R.dragable. + a + 3904123)
    String rutaImg = imagenURL + "a" + nImagen;

    //convierto el String en URI ?
    //Uri uriImagen = Uri.parse(rutaImg);

    //Agrega imagen al ImageView.
    Picasso.with(this)
            .load(rutaImg /*uriImagen*/) //con este método, a la derecha me aparece el texto "RequestCreator"
            .error(R.drawable.avestruz)
            .fit()
            .centerInside()
            .into(img_vS_img);
}
```

Comment: Edité mi pregunta y agregué la captura de pantalla del intento de cargar la imagen usando la variable 
        String rutaImg = imagenURL + "a" + nImagen; donde guarda (R.dragable.a3904123) //pero no funciona

Comment: que se obtiene como rutaImg, agrega un ejemplo por favor

Comment: Hola Jorgesys, el error, estaba en el uso del String. Como bien mencionó Sinner of the System, el enlace debe de ser un int. Muchas gracias por las molestias.

Comment: OK si es un recurso dentro del proyecto debe ser un int, pensé tratabas de cargar la imagen desde una url. saudos

Comment: Desde una URL lo intento en ésta pregunta, pero soy incapaz también. Se trataría de cargar las imágenes desde la URI del alojamiento en el disco duro del servidor.

Este es el enlace de la pregunta, por si sabrías responder.
[enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/449436/como-podr%c3%ada-mostrar-las-im%c3%a1genes-almacenadas-en-el-servidor-de-la-base-de-datos)

Un saludo y muchas gracias