# Mostrar imágenes en vista personalizada de ListView y SimpleCursorAdapter con android studio java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, picasso

Afortunadamente, y gracias a la ayuda de la comunidad, voy solucionando los problemas que tenía en mi aplicación.

Ahora os traslado otro de ellos, que por mucho que haya leído y seguido manuales y vídeos, tampoco lo logro solucionar.

Tengo una consulta que efectúo a la base de datos, y de ella obtengo el "Número", el "Nombre", y los dígitos que identifican la imagen de cada socio que tengo en la carpeta de la app "dragables"

Las imágenes están guardadas con el formato "a" + "Nº" (Este número es el que obtengo en la consulta)

Esta es la clase de la consulta:

```
public class ListItemSocios
{
    ConexionSQLServer miConexion = new ConexionSQLServer();

    public List<Map<String,String>> getlist()
    {
        List<Map<String,String>> data = null;
        data = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
        try
        {
            Statement stn = miConexion.metodoConexionBD().createStatement();
            ResultSet rst = stn.executeQuery("select f_ConsumerNO, f_ConsumerName, f_CardNO from t_b_Consumer");

            while (rst.next())
            {
                Map<String,String> dtname = new HashMap<String, String>();
                dtname.put("Numero", rst.getString("f_ConsumerNO"));
                dtname.put("Nombre", rst.getString("f_ConsumerName"));
                dtname.put("Foto", "a" + rst.getString("f_CardNO"));
                data.add(dtname);
            }
            rst.close();
            stn.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Desde aquí llamo a la clase anterior y muestro los datos en la lista:

```
public void metodoLlenarListaSocios() {
    ListView list_S = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_Socios);
    List<Map<String, String>> MyDataList = null;
    ListItemSocios MyData = new ListItemSocios();
    MyDataList = MyData.getlist();


    // definimos las imagenes que cargara el listview
    String[] nFotos = {"Foto"};
    int[] resId = new int[nFotos.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < nFotos.length; i++) {
        resId[i] = getResources().getIdentifier("a" + nFotos[i], "drawable", getPackageName());
    }
    String[] FromV = {"Numero", "Nombre", "Foto"};
    int[] Tow = {R.id.edt_socio_numero, R.id.edt_socio_nombre, R.id.img_socio_imagen};
    ad = new SimpleAdapter(PaginaListaS.this, MyDataList, R.layout.vista_socio, FromV, Tow);
    list_S.setAdapter(ad);
}
```

Los datos me los muestra bien, pero la imagen no hay manera y no se como hacerlo. Uso un SimpleCursorAdapter, y el alguna respuesta oí, que tendría que ser con un CustomCursorAdapter, pero no sabría como hacerlo.

Este es el código de la vista personalizada:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="114dp"
            android:layout_height="134dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_socio_imagen"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_socio_numero"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Socio"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/edt_socio_numero"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:textColor="@color/amarillo"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_socio_nombre"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Usuario"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/edt_socio_nombre"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:textColor="@color/amarillo"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

El resultado del código es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes llamarme inútil, pero siento decir, que no me entero. esto de los ArrayList, Map, adapter y Listas me sobrepasa.

No sé como aplicar el código que me has puesto. tengo MyDataList que se supone es lo que de devuelve MyData.getlist();. Y luego tengo tu código, pero no se como enlazar uno con el otro.

```
public void metodoLlenarListaSocios() {
    ListView list_S = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_Socios);
    List<Map<String, String>> MyDataList = null;
    ListItemSocios MyData = new ListItemSocios();
    MyDataList = MyData.getlist();

    for (int i = 0; i < MyDataList.size(); i++) {
        Map<String, String> socio = MyDataList.get(i);
        int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("a" + socio.get("Foto"), "drawable", getPackageName());
        socio.put("Foto", Integer.toString(resId));
    }
    String[] FromV = {"Numero", "Nombre", "Foto"};

    int[] Tow = {R.id.edt_socio_numero, R.id.edt_socio_nombre, R.id.img_socio_imagen};
    ad = new SimpleAdapter(PaginaListaS.this, MyDataList, R.layout.vista_socio, FromV, Tow);
    list_S.setAdapter(ad);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestamente no entiendo como se supone que este código definiría las imagenes que cargará el listview

```
// definimos las imagenes que cargara el listview
String[] nFotos = {"Foto"};
int[] resId = new int[nFotos.length];
for (int i = 0; i < nFotos.length; i++) {
    resId[i] = getResources().getIdentifier("a" + nFotos[i], "drawable", getPackageName());
}
```

Cosas que deberías notar:

1. Creas un array cuyo único elemento es la string `"Foto"`
2. Creas un int array del tamaño del array anterior (1)
3. El código dentro del `for` sólo se ejecutará una vez. Por lo que tu código puede reducirse a esto:

```
String[] nFotos = {"Foto"};
int[] resId = new int[1];
resId[0] = getResources().getIdentifier("a" + nFotos[0], "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Que en definitiva es lo mismo que

```
int[] resId = {getResources().getIdentifier("aFoto", "drawable", getPackageName())};
```

Además nunca vuelves a usar la variable `resId`.

La solución (que supongo es lo que intentaste hacer) es modificar la lista que le vas a pasar al adapter. Eso lo puedes hacer así

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyDataList.size(); i++) {
    Map<String, String> socio = MyDataList.get(i);
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("a" + socio.get("Foto"), "drawable", getPackageName());
    socio.put("Foto", Integer.toString(resId));
}
```

**EDIT**

En el método `getlist()` ya agregaste `"a"` delante del número de la foto. AL hacerlo denuevo obtienes un id invalido. Eliminando la "a" extra debería funcionar

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(socio.get("Foto"), "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Comment: No por favor, no te guíes de mi código, estoy muy perdido. La primera parte de tu respuesta se basa en tu solución a mi otra pregunta, que intenté adaptarla al ListView, y no fui capaz de ninguna manera. Dejé el código porque no me produce ningún error, pero no lo utilizo. Como te digo, estoy bastante perdido.

Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, lo intentaré mañana por la mañana, a ver si logro enterarme bien de lo que me indicas y lo acoplo a mi código.

De nuevo, muchísimas gracias

Comment: Vas a tener que perdonarme Sinner of the System, pero no logro enlazar tu solución con mi código. Desconozco como hacerlo. He editado mi pregunta y he puesto al final tu código inmerso en el mío, pero ahora no sabría como enviar los datos del ArrayList socio que has creado al adaptador. Mil perdones.

Comment: Lo copiaste bien. Me equivoqué yo por guiarme de tu código original. Ya edité la respuesta

Comment: Increible, alucinante, fantástico, maravilloso. Por fin puedo ver toda la funcionalidad de la aplicación. 

Gracias Sinner of the System, muchas gracias. 

Has conseguido que todo me funcione. Eternamente agradecido.

Comment: Un consejo final: esto está bien para ser tu primera app pero si quieres seguir desarrollando aplicaciones debes aprender desarrollo moderno. Es muy diferente a lo que has estado haciendo. por ejemplo para crear las vistas se usa kotlin en vez de xml. En la [documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/first) hay mucha información sobre por qué y cómo aprender kotlin.